# Getting rid of &amp; in ActionScript 2

Tags: actionscript-2

I have a flash 8 app that's reading an XML file.  In the file are nodes containing the & character.

When these values are rendered they come out as "&amp;"

How do I stop this?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify some 'Markdown madness'. Is that right Neil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try comparing the output of

```
childNodes.firstChild
```

to

```
childNodes.firstChild.nodeValue
```